# Why doesn't it clear the cache in an anonymous function in Laravel PHP

Tags: php, laravel

I was reviewing a portion of code where the forget cache was done but it only works with anonymous function but not with arrow functions

works

```
$collect->each(function($key) {
   Cache::forget($key);
});
```

it does not work

```
$collect->each(fn($key)=> Cache::forget($key));
```

I can fix it, or switch to traditional function. but my question is why this happens

PHP 7.4
Laravel 8.0

Comment: how about `$collect->each(fn($key)=> cache()->forget($key));`

Comment: @Snapey I can fix it, or switch to traditional function. but my question is why this happens

Comment: I was wondering if this was a general facades thing.

Comment: strange, i dont see how this can fail. The syntax is pretty much identical except that the arrow function automatically makes all the variables available.